# WCF Timeout Crash

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

If I use this code:

```
//in this timeout code necessary? 
ServiceClient.Timeout = 10;
ServiceClient.GetRestaurantsByNameAsync (MenuFinderApp.RestaurantSearchName);
ServiceClient.GetRestaurantsByNameCompleted += delegate(object sender, GetRestaurantsByNameCompletedEventArgs args) {

                    //code to show records

                    };
```

I return several records. If I wait about 5 - 10 minutes and execute the code again, I receive a timeout error. Why does this happen and how can I keep the connection open? Must I specify a timeout for 60 minutes? Here is my Web.config for the WCF Service:

```
 <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IMenuFinderAppService" closeTimeout="infinite" openTimeout="infinite" receiveTimeout="infinite" sendTimeout="infinite" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="500000" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="500000" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="500000" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
```

Comment: When it happens, what's the CommunicationState of the ServiceClient? One of the drags of WCF is if the client is faulted, you have to recreate it. In my classes that deal with services I add a method called "EnsureClient()" which checks to see if it's faulted and if it is, it calls Abort() on the connection and creates a new client object.

Comment: Correction: It's not a drag caused by WCF, but by the service client that VS.NET generates.

Comment: How do I get the communication state of the client? Can you send me some code? Do I correct the code in the service or in my client app?